# How can I modify this eggdrop TCL script to work a little differently

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I'm trying to set up a simple eggdrop bot to give a countdown til a certain event. The idea is that I give it a predetermined date and time, the user types !countdown and the bot replies with "There are x days, x hours, x minutes until it happens". This is the script as I found it (changed only to add the event's unixtime date in place of what it had), and running it on my eggdrop bot gives a response, but of course it isn't the response I needed (the important thing is that it worked at all).

I don't think there's a big difference between what it does and what I want it to do, but I have no idea how to correctly modify it. So I wondered if anyone here could show me how to do what I'm trying to do.

```
bind pub - !test countdown
proc countdown { nickname hostname handle channel arg } {  
    set date1 "1385798400"
    # finds the time and date now
    set now [unixtime]
    # counts the time passed scince now 
    incr now -$date1 
    # shows how long has passed since $date1 
    set then [duration $now] 
    puthelp "PRIVMSG $channel :date1 was: $then ago, $nickname | \([\
            clock format $date1 -format %d.%m.%Y] @ [\
            clock format $date1 -format %H:%M:%S]\)"    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hard part of working with dates is parsing and formatting, but you've already got utility commands to do that (`duration` and `clock format`). To work out the time remaining to an event in the future, you've just got to make sure that you do timestamp<sub>future event</sub> - timestamp<sub>now</sub> in your calculations.

```
proc countdown {nickname hostname handle channel arg} {
    set date1 "1385798400"
    # finds the time and date now
    set now [unixtime]

    set left [duration [expr {$date1 - $now}]]
    # Easier to store complex stuff in a variable and substitute stuff in
    set formatted [clock format $date1 -format "(%d.%m.%Y @ %H:%M:%S"}]

    puthelp "PRIVMSG $channel :date1 will be: $left in the future, $nickname | $formatted"
}
```

Just `bind` that and off you go.

Comment: Note that duration does not display the right time in all cases. Try the date of your birth with your next birthday. It should say "X years", but it actually returns "X years, Y days Z seconds". If you want the timedifference between two dates, `duration` is not the best choice.